# Python's requests is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-requests

The python request is giving 200 status code even though proxy server is powered off. While experimenting, I realized it's giving status code 200 for all the IP address from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.

[image: the IP is powered off but still got 200]

Question:

1. Why it's working? Does it go for localhost if proxy doesn't work?
2. Is there any alternative which will throw an error or at least give connection refused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the proxies parameter takes two arguments http and https. Since you are using an https request you need to use https key in your proxies dictionary

```
proxies = {
        "http" : http_proxy,
        "https": http_proxy,
    }
```

This should solve your problem.

Also you can try only https in your code and it should run properly

For your second question i would suggest you using the requests.get() line in try block and print error message of couldn't find proxy server in except.

Comment: The proxies dictionary doesn't **have** to have 2 entries. It depends what you want/need to achieve

Answer (score 3):

Do not post screen captures. They are hard to read and we can't copy/paste the text.

You are making a HTTPS request but only registered a proxy for HTTP so your proxy isn't being used. The `google.com` host is being connected to without the involvement of any proxy on your end.

I'll also point out that the use of HTTP, rather than HTTPS, is (or should be) very rare in the year 2024. The only time I use plain HTTP is when connecting to a service on my LAN that I wrote long ago and have not updated to use secure HTTPS connections.